As a customer, what should I expect at a hotel impacted by the Unite Here hotel workers strike?
Next week I will be staying at a hotel I know to be impacted by the ongoing Unite Here "Respect Our Work" strike: it's listed on their map as "Strike: Workers are asking guests not to eat, meet or sleep at this hotel."
Obviously each hotel will be different, but generally speaking, as a customer staying there what should I expect? Noisy picket lines, less housekeeping services, closed amenities, business as usual?
And yes, I am seriously considering changing my hotel, but at this late date choices are quite limited, prices high than my employer's cap, and many alternatives are also striking or listed as "at risk".

It's going to depend on a lot of things, such as how many workers are taking part in the strike. Since hypothetically you could see anything from no disruption to the hotel being closed, your best bet is to contact the hotel.

One of my employers got picketed once for a while (some union dispute, I think). The picketers where at the front door (which was on the main drag) with signs but otherwise didn't bother anyone. I asked one of them what their beef was. Answer: "I have no idea, I just get paid to stand here". Apparently the affected employees couldn't be bother to picket themselves and so hired cheap day laborers to do it for them. My hotel was pretty much next door but not affected.

Did you contact the hotel and ask? I'm guessing that the actual implementation and consequences of the labor action will vary a lot from location to location, so a generic answer may be impossible.

If the employees are striking I would actually expect the hotel to be closed with no possibility for you to sleep there. I don't know anything about this particular strike but you should have some kind of backup plan if that happens.

In the end I cancelled my booking in solidarity and stayed at another hotel, but as a data point, I walked past the currently-striking Palace SF and this protest was going on outside the main entrance:

What the photo doesn't capture is the drums, vuvuzelas and chanting, so that's a ✅ for the noisy picket lines. Similar protests are happening at other striking hotels, including the one I was staying at.
I'm not sure how long they will be there (I've now seen them in the afternoon and evening, but not the morning), but it would not be particularly pleasant to try to work or sleep in the hotel right now.
